# How do I delete the last element added into a linked-list in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm using pointers for the first time.  I have a program that inserts numbers into a linked list, prints the list, and deletes specific numbers from the list.  It works except when I try to delete the number that was inserted last.

Node.h

```
#ifndef Node_h
#define Node_h

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node
{
public:
    int data;
    Node *next;

public:
Node();
};

#endif
```

Node.cpp

```
#include "Node.h"

Node::Node()
{
}
```

LinkedList.h

```
#ifndef LinkedList_h
#define LinkedList_h

#include "Node.h"

class LinkedList
{
    private:
    Node *pL;

public:
    LinkedList();
    void insert(int nr1);
    void deleteNr(int nr1);
    void printL();
};

#endif
```

LinkedList.cpp
    // This program is creating a "linked-list" of numbers

```
#include "LinkedList.h"

LinkedList::LinkedList()
{
    pL = NULL;
}

void LinkedList::insert(int nr1)
{
    Node *p = new Node;
    p->data = nr1;
    p->next = pL;
    pL = p;
}

void LinkedList::deleteNr(int nr1)
{
    Node *p = pL;
    Node *p2 = pL;
    while (p != NULL & p->data != nr1)
    {
        p2 = p;
        p = p->next;
    }

    if (p != NULL)
    {
        p2->next = p->next;
        delete p;
    }
}

void LinkedList::printL()
{
    Node *p = pL;

    while (p != NULL)
    {
        cout << p->data << "-> ";
        p = p->next;
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "LinkedList.h"

int menu();

//////// main /////////
int main()
{
    int choice1, nr1;
    LinkedList lk1;

    choice1 = menu();

    while (choice1 <= 3)
    {
        if (choice1 == 1)
        {
            cout << "Enter number." << endl;
            cin >> nr1;
            lk1.insert(nr1);
        }

        else if (choice1 == 2)
        {
            cout << "Enter number." << endl;
            cin >> nr1;
            lk1.deleteNr(nr1);
        }

        else if (choice1 == 3)
        {
            lk1.printL();
            cout << endl << endl;
        }

        else if (choice1 == 4)
        {
            cout << "Exit the program." << endl;
            system("pause");
            exit(1);
        }

        choice1 = menu();
    } // end while loop
}

int menu()
{
    int choice1;

    cout << "1. Insert a number into the linked-list." << endl;
    cout << "2. Delete a number from the linked-list." << endl;
    cout << "3. Print the linked-list." << endl;
    cout << "4. Exit the program." << endl;
    cout << "Enter choice." << endl;
    cin >> choice1;

    return choice1;
}
```

Comment: Homework?  What happens when you try to delete the last inserted item?

Comment: Yes this is a homework assignment.  When I try to delete the last inserted item it crashes.

Comment: Just a side note, in your delete function, you have an `&` where it needs to be `&&`. They do different things.

Comment: Also, just so you know, if you are using a default constructor, you can simply eliminate the lines `public:
Node();` from your Node.h file and you don't need the Node.cpp file. You could also put the Node class definition in the LinkedList.h file. Although I would recommend instead to keep the constructor and use it to initialize data to NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add code to deal with the case where the given input corresponds to the first item in the list.

```
void LinkedList::deleteNr(int nr1)
{
   Node *p = pL;

   if ( p != NULL && p->data == nr1 )
   {
      pL = p->next;
      delete p;
      return;
   }

   Node *p2 = pL;
   while (p != NULL && p->data != nr1)
   {
      p2 = p;
      p = p->next;
   }

   if (p != NULL)
   {
      p2->next = p->next;
      delete p;
   }
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly.  Thank you!  Could you briefly explain what I did wrong and what you corrected?  I'm pretty confused.

Comment: @user3254558, when you are trying to delete the first item, the member variable `pL` has to point to the next element. If you don't, `pL` is left pointing to an element that has been deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that normally, p2 is one node behind p in the list, but if the first node is to be deleted, then the first while loop in the delete function had 0 iterations and p2 and p are the same. The head is deleted, but pL is not updated. It's just pointing to unallocated memory. This might make it look like the node was not deleted, or it could cause a segmentation fault and crash. Either way, it is the wrong behavior. You need to make sure to check for the case that the node to be deleted is the first node and update pL.

Try something like this

```
void LinkedList::deleteNr(int nr1)
{
    Node *p = pL;
    Node *p2 = pL;
    if(p != NULL && nr1 == p->data)
    {
        pL = p->next;
        delete p;
        return;
    }

    while (p != NULL && p->data != nr1)
    {
        p2 = p;
        p = p->next;
    }

    if (p != NULL)
    {
        p2->next = p->next;
        delete p;
    }
}
```

If you want to be able to delete *all* instances of `nr1` in the linked list, you'll need to add another loop:

```
void LinkedList::deleteNr(int nr1)
{
    Node *p = pL;
    while(p != NULL && nr1 == p->data)
    {
        pL = p->next;
        delete p;
        p = pL;
    }
    Node *p2 = pL;

    while (p != NULL)
    {
        p2 = p;
        p = p->next;
        if(nr1 == p->data)
        {
            p2->next = p->next;
            delete p;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works and doesn't work.  Yes, you can delete the last number entered because it will delete the numbers in the list in the reverse order that they were entered, but you can't delete specific numbers.

Comment: @user3254558 I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: @user3254558 This will delete all instances of the number nr1 in the linked list.

Comment: For some reason I only saw the top portion of the code and tried that.  When I went to delete a specific number from the list, it would delete the most recent entry regardless of what I chose.

Comment: @user3254558 The top portion of the code shouldn't do that either.

Comment: @user3254558 That is not what the first portion of the code does. The first snippet of code will delete _the first instance_ of `nr1` in the list. The second snipped will delete _all instances_ of `nr1` from the list.

Comment: @user3254558 Also note, that I just changed the code to make it a bit better.

Answer (score -1):

```
void LinkedList::deleteLast()
{

Node *p = pL;

if(p == NULL)
   return;
else if(p->next == NULL) {
   p = NULL;
 }
 else {
  while (p->next->next != NULL)
  {
    p = p->next;
  }

  p->next = NULL; 
 }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is really the answer that the OP was looking for. The title of the question is a little misleading. Also, what language is this code in? It looks like a combination of Java and C++.

Comment: This is c++ language.  Is this a brand new function specifically to delete the last element and to be called in the main function?

Comment: @user3254558 It uses lower case null which is Java. Also doesn't delete nodes, which is also Java-like.